# load NSPanel from NSView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, nsviewcontroller

I'm trying to load a NSPanel when to send message when something happen in the NSView. But I can not figure out how to call the NSPanel from the NSView or how to call a method from the NSView class

Here is how I'm loading the NSView:

```
NSViewController *myVC = [[songView alloc] initWithNibName:@"songView" bundle:nil];
```

My question for you guys is how can access or call methods from the NSView class to my NSWindowController.

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch the mouseDown event and call your method . For the NSPanel you can do in 2 ways

1) You can create in IB and put an outlet connection to panel

2) You can create in programetically .

You can call orderFront to bring it front. Please refer this link for that
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000013-SW32